# password recovery control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

i would like to create a forgot password control that follows this steps:

1- the user enters his email.
2- an email is send to the user containing the url which has the authentication ticket.

my problem is i cant create an authentication ticket and embed it within the url here is an example i used:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new
        FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, ttb1.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
            true, string.Empty);
```

but the ticket isn't included in the url, how can i do that , thanks.

using asp.net 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what i was looking for:
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Password_Recovery.aspx

Comment: Treat the mentioned article like a starting idea only because of the serious security issue - the user's GUID is passed in the unlock url. This way, once the hacker learns the user id, he/she can freely change passwords for your users. A simple workaround would be to create an additional table to store unlock requests with two columns, request GUID and username. In the unlock url you pass the request GUID (instead of User's GUID) and you find a username in your request table for the GUID which comes with a request.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla - You are right, i should keep both the request guid and user guid separate and add the request id to the unlock link .thank you